# Как изменить цвет подсказки в поле ввода

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Всем привет, у меня появился очередной вопрос по html5, появился новый атрибут placeholder. В связи с этим у меня появился вопрос, возможно ли изменить цвет этой подсказке с серого, допустим на красный. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью css или нужно использовать javascript?

Answer (score 3):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #f00; } /* webkit browsers */
:-moz-placeholder { color: #f00; }           /* firefox 4 - 18 */
::-moz-placeholder { color: #f00; }          /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #f00; }      /* ie 10+ */
```

Подробнее: [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120152/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css).

Примеры: [вот здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/KyVXK/) и [вот тут](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/placeholder-style.php).